# android - is it possible to update the Android Dev Phone 2 sold by google to 2.1 OS?

Tags: android, version

If I have a Android Dev Phone 2 phone that comes with 1.6, can I upgrade it to Android 2.1 ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. The latest supported version is 1.6. If they will release an update I think you will find it here:

http://developer.htc.com/google-io-device.html

Answer (score 0):

It is true that 1.6 is the latest stable official version from HTC.  But you can try installing an unofficial rom from androidspin.com

I found these instructions useful for getting OpenEclair installed on my Google Ion device. These instructions are a little dated.  There is a new version of Open Eclair available.  WARNING: I am not responsible if you brick your phone.  That said, it went pretty smooth for me.  You just have to read carefully (Google for stuff you don't understand, and for the latest versions of stuff) and cross your fingers.  Good luck. And don't expect everything to work in an unofficial rom.  Things like GPS or Bluetooth could be non-functional depending on the rom you install.

http://denraf.be/content/howto-android-21-g1adp1dream